# 'to be smart' or 'to get smart'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was reading a blog post, titled "7 Ways to Get Smart", and it just come to my mind, If it can be titled also "7 Ways to be Smart". I really feel lost, when I try to distinguish between 'to be smart' and 'to get smart'.

Considering the two statments :

```
- 7 Ways to Get Smart
- 7 Ways to Be Smart
```

Is the first statment is strongly the right one ? or both are already correct?

Comment: Perhaps you would be so kind as to post a link to the blog post. But it occurs to me, too, that 1) this is a headline, in which customary grammatical rules do not always apply; and 2) there may be an intentional reference to the 1960's US TV series / 2008 movie, both entitled "Get Smart".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the really correct phrase is "7 Ways to Become Smart". (I am assuming that the blog post is about suggestions for *becoming smart*, rather than suggestions for *being smart*, which seems like a wholly different game altogether.)

"To get" is frequently used in all possible contexts, usually as a replacement for verbs "to be" or "to have". The latter phrasing is usually seen as more correct.

Answer (score 1):

What @Newb suggested is pretty good, but to add a bit more detail about the difference between those two phrases, consider someone who *is* smart just naturally; that is *being smart*. However the blog post is trying to tell people how to *become* smart/smarter than what they are at the moment.

So, **to be smart** implies the current state of being smart, where **to become/get smart** refers to improvements in skills to have a different state of the current one.

Comment: Btw, @User doesn't work in the body of answers.

Comment: I know @Newb; it just makes it easier for other readers to see what's going on, if they're reading it after quite a while the question is asked, without paying attention to the usernames, etc. (:

Comment: Okay, fair enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Newb states, "7 Ways to Become Smart" is the best usage.  However, the blogger may have chosen "7 Ways to Get Smart" as an allusion to the television show "Get Smart".  Using rhetorical devices, especially allusions, is a standard headline writing technique, even if it makes the headline less grammatical.